# Невиновен таки / невиновен-таки

Tags: орфография

Из-за того что Лопатин говорит, что *-таки* через дефис с любым подлежащим пишется, приводя пример с *рад-таки*, я колебаюсь как осиновый лист посейчас. Как правильно?

`Я был невиновен-таки / невиновен таки.`

`Это не ясно-таки / ясно таки?` (Категория состояния.)

`Я – это кот-таки / кот таки.`

`Луг некошенный-таки / некошенный таки был.`

`Луг не кошен-таки / не кошен таки был.`

РАН: http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=75#pp75.

Comment: Даже в простейших случаях могут быть варианты:
Всё-таки сделали;
Всё таки сделали.

Answer (score 0):

Во всех случаях раздельно:

*Я был **невиновен таки***;

*Это не **ясно таки***;

*Я — это **кот таки***;

*Луг **некошенный таки** был*;

*Луг не **кошен таки** был*.

«Грамота.ру»:

[image: частица таки]

***Невиновен*** — краткое прилагательное, но не глагол и не наречие, так что раздельно. ***Ясно*** — тоже краткое прилагательное (оно не может быть СКС, т. к. есть подлежащее ***это***), так что раздельно. ***Кот*** — вообще существительное, поэтому раздельно. ***Некошенный*** — причастие — раздельно. ***Кошен*** — краткое причастие — раздельно.

Следует заметить, что *не кошен* нужно написать **раздельно**, т. к. это краткое причастие, а краткие причастия всегда пишутся с НЕ **раздельно**.

Comment: В РАНе по-другому.

Comment: А давайте вопрос зададим, кто согласен с РАНом, а кто с источниками, где по-другому, — в том числе и «Грамота»)

Comment: Хоть вы задайте, хоть я. Как смотрите на это?)

Comment: Давайте вы-с таки.

Comment: Хорошо, я задам, но завтра.

Comment: Вы посейчас не задали вопрос.

Comment: Почему? Задал. Он называется «О частице ТАКИ».