# О частице «таки»

Tags: орфография, слитно-дефис, частица-таки, ран, грамота-ру

Всем здравствуйте! Недавно Леопольд задавал [вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475630/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8) о частице ТАКИ. Из-за этого возникли вопросы о еë правописании.

Вот как пишет [«Грамота.ру»](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8&all=x):

[image: таки]

**Но!**

Вот как пишет [РАН](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=75#pp75):

[image: таки2]

Какой из этих вариантов, по вашему мнению, более правильный? Мы с Леопольдом не можем-таки разобраться.