# Все-таки сделали. Или: Все таки сделали. О загадочной частице "таки"

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис, частица

**Оба** варианта верны или нет?  А если верны, то в каком **контексте?**

(1) ***Всё-таки** сделали.*

(2) ***Всё таки** сделали.*

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ (философия на тему)**

Да что же в ней такого **загадочного?** Правило есть, словарь — пожалуйста, а **вопросы не кончаются.** И даже споры! Помнится, в одной из тем обсуждали  очень "неправильное" слово ***"уже-таки".***

Да и к использованию этой частицы **в речи** тоже есть вопросы. **Нужна ли она вообще?** В некоторых случаях бывает очень кстати, если она действительно уместна и выполняет свою **функцию**. Но вот избыточная или неправильная **стилизация** выглядит надоедливо и утомительно.

Так что **загадки** все-таки есть. Вот любопытная тема  **[с  форума](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475630/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8).** Чем любопытна?  Там есть такой комментарий:  *Даже в простейших случаях могут быть варианты: **Всё-таки сделали. Всё таки сделали**.*

Может быть, он намекает нам на причину множества вопросов?

Так в чем же **загадочность этой частицы?** Как ее **правильно** использовать?

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

**Орфографический** словарь: ***таки*** – частица, пишется через дефис с предшествующим глаголом (вернулся-таки), наречием (довольно-таки, прямо-таки) и в словах всё-таки, так-таки; в остальных случаях – раздельно (он таки приедет)

**Большой толковый** словарь: -***ТАКИ***, частица. Разг. Тем не менее, всё же, однако. Дождался-таки свободы. Успел-таки на поезд. Таки навязался в попутчики. Принёс-таки двойку! Она таки сдержала слово.